# Does number of columns in a table affect performance if you don't use them in a join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 49 columns and I need to add two more. I could add another table related to that one with those new columns to avoid making the table bigger and bigger.

However I would like to know how much would affect performance having 2 more columns in that table if they are not used in joins?

Is there really a difference in performance doing the join of table A with table B if A has 4 columns or 100 if you only use 3 of them?

Also the table is not highly populated, it doesn't even have 500 rows but would like to know as the DBA doesn't like it just to understand his point of view.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I'll edit to explain that my only work in this table is to add 2 more columns to the existing 49 that the table currently holds and that they will be bit columns. So that's why I wanted to know if increasing the columns size would impact the performance at all assuming they never do a select * when they join with that table.

Comment: If you don't use the columns in your queries then it has no effect. (But I suspect you use them in _some_ query, why else would you add the columns.)

Comment: 50 columns? Seems like horrible table design.

Comment: That should not affect your decision whether to create more columns or not. It's about maintenance and the performance of queries if you have similar columns(f.e. `Value1` ... `Value100`). Create a related table where you store those values. Then it's also much easier to write queries which select records where at least one value is > 100 (for example).

Comment: I know is a horrible design and I appreciate everything I just want to know if having a table with tons of columns affect performance if you just use a couple of them on queries or whatever. I didn't design this database, just needed to add 2 bit columns to the table and wanted to know if there could be an impact in existing sps or code (assuming they don't use select *).

Comment: If you add a second table, that means you now have related information in 2 different locations.  That adds complexity to how you maintain that data.  I also don't think that 50 columns is inherently a bad design.  That depends on teh application and what data is actually stored in the table.

Comment: Sometimes you really do need a wide table.  Our application has an inventory table that has 43 columns.  They are all necessary to track the many different things that can happen on a given date.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer is: does these new columns will be empty most of the time for your rows ?

- Yes: Maybe you can add these columns to the main table. Depends if you needs them most of the time you select rows in this table.
- No: Create a new table and join. Empty column for each row is useless disk space.

NB: 50 columns seems like horrible anyway...

Comment: I agree but I didn't ask to discuss if is a good design or not. My only work in that DB is adding 2 more column to that table. Edited my main question explaining that.

Answer (score 0):

Adding these two columns to your table should not significantly impact performance, in particular as your table stores less than 500 rows. Saying that, your DBA does not like this as it does't follow best practices for table design, in particular if many column values are NULL/empty and this design will not scale well. However, unless you  anticipate that this table is going to grow in size rapidly, adding two columns should not pose a performance problem.

Comment: That is what I wanted to know. I don't like it either having 51 columns. But I just feel it completely unfair that the problem arises now, when going from 49 to 51 columns, not any moment before, when they added more and more stuff to that table.

Answer (score 0):

If you add another table then I assume you will have to use joins to access that data properly. Really this could end up costing more than the two new attributes would added to the single table.

If your table could be refactored then that would be the best option, but if not then you would only lose efficiency by attempting to do so. Dont make a second table simply to stay under the 50 attributes. Two columns added to 49 is not going to be an unworkable load by any measure, but there could be other reasons to redesign your table. If you have a bunch of empty or null cells then you are wasting resources and giving your system more work to do, finding a way to eliminate these would undoubtedly have a greater effect on performance than adding a column or two

Comment: That's what I think, more so considering that is a bit column. There are now 461 values that means less than 1000 bits, the names of the columns could even cost more memory than the data in the columns. I'll probably have to create the other table because I don't have a choice here, just wanted to know if I was crazy for thinking that two bit columns wouldn't impact at all.

Comment: Would it be possible to refactor your table to make two or more smaller sized ones?

Comment: Refactor is not a word we know the meaning of :) no, it won't be possible at all. I will have to create the new table (plus triggers for the audit db and stuff like that) meaning I'll have to waste almost two days for making this change but that's how we roll.

Comment: To refactor is simply to change the internal structure of something while leaving the external function intact. It is a common practice for anything that undergoes multiple changes as the original architecture may not remain suitable after all of the changes have been made. In plain English, optimise is a better word. If it is not possible I still would not worry as you should not be experiencing unacceptable drops in performance given the scale of your changes.